# Особенность размещение элементов в std::deque

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    std::deque<int>d{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

    for (auto & i : d)
        std::cout << i << ":" << &i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> output:
>
> 0:0054FB78
>
> 1:0054FB7C
>
> 2:0054FB80
>
> 3:0054FB84
>
> 4:00550288
>
> 5:0055028C
>
> 6:00550290
>
> 7:00550294
>
> 8:005502C8
>
> 9:005502CC

Можно сделать вывод, что элементы размещены следующим видом

|0 1 2 3|->|4 5 6 7|->|8 9 ...

то есть кусками по 4 элемента.

В чем преимущество данной реализации?

Comment: Что то среднее между `std::list` и `std::vector`

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6292332/4928642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дек должен обеспечить компромисс между быстрым добавлением в конец и снятием элемента из начала (доступ за O(1)) и легким расширением. 
Это можно обеспечить при хранении очереди в циклическом виде в динамическом массиве, который при необходимости расширяется

При увеличении размера умножением на определенный коэффициент (например, 2) обеспечивается амортизированная сложность расширения O(1) на элемент, однако при этом могут быть моменты довольно долгой перезаписи. Кроме того, такой подход требует выделения единого куска памяти (возможно - большого).

Так устроен `vector`. Ему требуется обеспечивать быстрый доступ к произвольному элементу, а перед деком такой задачи не стоит.

Видимо, с целью избавления от этих недостатков выбран метод хранения дека в наборе чанков определённого размера, указатели на которые лежат в векторе.

Картинка [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl/6292437#6292437)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

> The storage of a deque is automatically expanded and contracted as
>   needed. Expansion of a deque is cheaper than the expansion of a
>   std::vector because it does not involve copying of the existing
>   elements to a new memory location.

Answer (score 2):

В отличии класса `std::list` где элементы хранятся поодиночке, преимущество - запись

```
0->1->2->3
```

И вектора `std::vector`  где элементы хранятся вместе, преимущество - чтение

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Класс `std::deque` предлагает среднее меджу вышеуказаными, он хранит данные в *"кусках"* и является компромиссом. Cкорость чтения и записи что-то "среднее" этими двумя потому-что ему не приходится итерироватся по каждому элементу одновременно не приходится пересоздавать весь массив для вставки новых элементов.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]->[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Произвольный доступ в std::deque согласно документации имеет трудоёмкость O(1).
Из вашего описания следует, что трудоёмкость произвольного доступа O(N/4) = O(N).
Значит вы не правы.